# Python Open file in binary and change endiannes of selected bites per line

Tags: python, binary

I need to open a file in binary and change the endiannes for all the bytes in the same column.

Line lenght is 15.

I need to change the endiannes for bytes in 7-10 position

[image]

Comment: Why not the first and the last two lines?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How are you currently reading the file now? You can exploit the `struct` library from python maybe....

Comment: I'm new in binary edit in python